# Sed/awk for String to integer conversion of a csv column in shell

Tags: awk, sed, integer

I need 7th column of a csv file to be converted from float to decimal. It's a huge file and I don't want to use while read for conversion. Any shortcuts with awk?

Input:

```
"xx","x","xxxxxx","xxx","xx","xx"," 00000001.0000"  
"xx","x","xxxxxx","xxx","xx","xx"," 00000002.0000"  
"xx","x","xxxxxx","xxx","xx","xx"," 00000005.0000"  
"xx","x","xxxxxx","xxx","xx","xx"," 00000011.0000"
```

Output:

```
"xx","x","xxxxxx","xxx","xx","xx","1"  
"xx","x","xxxxxx","xxx","xx","xx","2"  
"xx","x","xxxxxx","xxx","xx","xx","5"   
"xx","x","xxxxxx","xxx","xx","xx","11"
```

Tried these, worked. But anything simpler ?

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="\",\""} {$7 = sprintf("%.0f", $7)} 1' $test > $test1
awk '{printf("%s\"\n", $0)}' $test1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {gsub(/"/, "", $7); $7="\"" $7+0 "\""; print}' file
```

Output:

```
"xx","x","xxxxxx","xxx","xx","xx","1"
"xx","x","xxxxxx","xxx","xx","xx","2"
"xx","x","xxxxxx","xxx","xx","xx","5"
"xx","x","xxxxxx","xxx","xx","xx","11"
```

> `gsub(/"/, "", $7)`: removes all `"` from $7

> `$7+0`: Reduces the number in $7 to minimal representation

Comment: Worked like a charm. Just what I needed. Thanks for the detailed explanation too

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` program.

```
awk -v s1="\"" -v OFS="," '{$NF = s1 ($NF + 0) s1} 1' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation would be, setting `OFS` as `,` then in main program; in each line's last field keeping only digits and covering last field with `"`, re-shuffle the fields and printing edited/non-edited all lines.

Comment: There is a closing parenthesis missing.

Can you explain what does $NF do ?

Comment: @GD, sorry that was a typo fixed it now, should fly now.

Comment: @GD, `NF` is the awk variable holding the number of fields in the current record. Since fields are numbered from one, NF is also the number of the _last field_. So `$NF` is the contents of the last field.

Comment: @glennjackman


"xx","x","xxxxxx","xxx","xx","xx",",1"  
"xx","x","xxxxxx","xxx","xx","xx",",2"

I get like this.. extra comma added

Comment: @GD, With your shown samples it worked fine for me. Please do mention for which line its not working, please do mention sample line in backticks in comments to make them visible in code tags like `this is a test`.

Comment: @Ravinder, the first awk body only needs `{$NF = s1 ($NF + 0) s1}` -- need to add the leading  quote. Also, assigning $NF already rewrites $0, don't need `$1=$1`

Comment: @GD, could you please check my updated code now and let me know if this works for you?

Answer (score 3):

Another simple `awk` solution:

```sh
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="\",\""} {$NF = $NF+0 "\""} 1' file

"xx","x","xxxxxx","xxx","xx","xx","1"
"xx","x","xxxxxx","xxx","xx","xx","2"
"xx","x","xxxxxx","xxx","xx","xx","5"
"xx","x","xxxxxx","xxx","xx","xx","11"
```